# Knockoutjs one to many mapping not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

In this following code snippet I am creating parent child view model using knockoutjs mapping plugin.I am not getting any error in mapping But when I am running the application it's throwing the error **name is not defined.**

```js
data = {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "Name": "Microsoft",
                    "Address": "USA",
                    "WebPage": "SS",
                    "Employees": [
                        {
                            "Id": 1,
                            "FirstName": "sadsasa",
                            "LastName": "ADF",
                            "Twitter": "dfd",
                            "WebPage": "sdfdf"
                        },
                        {
                            "Id": 2,
                            "FirstName": "sadsasa",
                            "LastName": "ADF",
                            "Twitter": "dfd",
                            "WebPage": "sdfs"
                        },
                        {
                            "Id": 3,
                            "FirstName": "sadsasa",
                            "LastName": "ADF",
                            "Twitter": "dfd",
                            "WebPage": "sfdfs"
                        }
                        ]
                    };
        var mapping = {
            'Employees': {
                create: function (options) {
                    alert(options);
                    return new PersonViewModel(options.data);
                }
            }
        }
        function PersonViewModel(data) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        }
        function CompanyViewModel(data) {
    
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this);
        }
        var company;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/Greet',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
    
                    data = JSON.stringify(result);
                    company = new CompanyViewModel(data);
                    console.log(company);
                    ko.applyBindings(company);
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert(e);
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
        FirstName:  <span data-bind="text:Name"></span>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: Answer of following question will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091175/unable-to-map-the-data-using-mapping-plugin-knockout/27098481#27098481

Comment: @dotnetstep i got much of my little knowledge on mapping via your help (the posted link). cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to do some small modifications in your code .

**View Model :**

```
 function PersonViewModel(data) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data,mapping,this);
    }

    function CompanyViewModel(data) {
        self.childlist=ko.observableArray();
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this);
        self.childlist.push(new PersonViewModel()); //child array
    }
```

**View :**

```
<div>
    <b>FirstName:</b>  <span data-bind="text:Name"></span>
    <div data-bind="foreach:Employees">
    <span data-bind="text:Id"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/y7fv998k/)

Do let me know incase of any issues .