# handling events and manual subscription on dropdownlist change knockout

Tags: knockout.js

Here I have the 'eventschemas' data which is an array of ['schema' and 'schemaconditiondetails'] which in turn is an array of ['schemadetail'(which has 'schemapropety', 'propertyvalue' and 'propertycondition') and 'schemaconditions'(which in turn is an array of 'propertycondition')]  .

I'm trying to call an event 'setcondition' on 'propertycondition' dropdownlist change. I also have an manual subscribe call on the same change..

The manual subscribe call and the event call is not getting called in javascript.
Moreover because the event call is thrown from html, its throwing the following error:

Message: Unable to process binding "event: function (){return {change:setcondition} }"

Message: setcondition is not defined

This error message goes off if I do a $parent.setcondition but it still does not show the console.log message

My html code:

```
 <div data-bind="with: g">
            <div>
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: gname" />
            </div>


            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr data-bind="with: gdetails">
                        <td>

                            <select data-bind="options: $root.eventschemas, optionsText: 'schema', value: eventschemacondition().schema"></select>

                            <table data-bind="with:eventschemacondition().schema">
                                <tbody data-bind="foreach: schemaconditiondetails">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="text" data-bind='value: schemadetail.schemaproperty' style="width:150px" /></td>
                                        <td data-bind="with: schemadetail">
                                            <select data-bind="options: $parent.schemaconditions, optionsText:'propertycondition', value: propertycondition, event: {change: setcondition}" style="width:150px"></select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td><input type="text" data-bind='value: schemadetail.propertyvalue' style="width:150px" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

My javascript code:

```
 var eventschemas = [{
            "schema": "Test",
            "schemaconditiondetails": [{
                "schemadetail": { "schemaproperty": "Test1", "propertyvalue": 12, "propertycondition": undefined },
                "schemaconditions": [{
                    "propertycondition": "propertycondition1"
                }, {
                    "propertycondition": "propertycondition2"
                }]
            }, {
                "schemadetail": { "schemaproperty": "Test2", "propertyvalue": 42, "propertycondition": undefined },
                "schemaconditions": [{
                    "propertycondition": "propertycondition1"
                }, {
                    "propertycondition": "propertycondition2"
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "schema": "Another Test",
            "schemaconditiondetails": [{
                "schemadetail": { "schemaproperty": "Another Test1", "propertyvalue": 12, "propertycondition": undefined },
                "schemaconditions": [{
                    "propertycondition": "propertycondition1"
                }, {
                    "propertycondition": "propertycondition2"
                }]
            }, {
                "schemadetail": { "schemaproperty": "Another Test2", "propertyvalue": 12, "propertycondition": undefined },
                "schemaconditions": [{
                    "propertycondition": "propertycondition1"
                }, {
                    "propertycondition": "propertycondition2"
                }]
            }]
        }];


        var AppScope = function () {
            function EventSchemaConditionDetails(data) {
                this.schemaproperty = ko.observable(data.schemaproperty);
                this.propertycondition = ko.observable(data.propertycondition);
                this.propertyvalue = ko.observable(data.propertyvalue);
                this.propertycondition.subscribe(function (newText) {
                    console.log(newText + "subscribe fired");
                });
                this.setcondition = function (name) {
                    console.log("event fired");
                    self.propertycondition(name);
                };
            };
            function EventSchemaCondition(data) {
                this.schema = ko.observable(data.schema);
                this.schemaconditiondetails = ko.observableArray(data.schemadetail);

            };
            function Gdetails(data) {
                this.eventschemacondition = ko.observable(data.eventschemacondition);
            };
            function G(data) {
                this.gname = ko.observable(data.gname);
                this.gdetails = ko.observable(data.gdetails);
            };
            function GsViewModel() {
                var self = this;
                self.g = ko.observable(new G({
                    gname: "gname",
                    gdetails: new Gdetails({
                        eventschemacondition: new EventSchemaCondition({
                            schema: "",
                            schemaconditiondetails: ko.observableArray([new EventSchemaConditionDetails({
                                schemaproperty: "",
                                propertycondition: "",
                                propertyvalue: ""
                            })])
                        })
                    })
                }));

                self.eventschemas = eventschemas;
            }
            ko.applyBindings(new GsViewModel());
        }();
```

All help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: `arnab` i see no error when i try it http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/74dh736s/4/  . help me reproduce the error by forking the fiddle & i will try to help it .

Comment: @supercool The code without event code in html is here-http://jsfiddle.net/74dh736s/5/ Here $data does not change on change of propertycondition,  now if I add ', event: {change: setcondition}' as in here-http://jsfiddle.net/74dh736s/6/ you get the error. you can not see it in jsfiddle but if you do it in browser- you get the error Message: setcondition is not defined, now if I make change: $parent.setcondition as here- http://jsfiddle.net/74dh736s/7/ , the error goes off but setcondition event still does not fire on propertycondition change.. let me know if you need any more info- Thanks4help

Comment: @supercool As for the subscribe problem, you can  in all fiddles see the subscribe is not firing. vide.. this.propertycondition.subscribe

Comment: Check the answer . when you change now you can see the changes reflected in the preview . Cheers .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well that was a simple mistake you have done there . you are directly assigning plane array to `self.eventschemas` instead you need to convert array content to observable's so two way binding will be intact between view and model

**View Model:**

```
        self.eventschemas = ko.observableArray(ko.mapping.fromJS(eventschemas)());
```

You can see i'm using `ko.mapping` if you are new to that dont be scared at first look its simple just refer **[knockout docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)** pretty good content available there . well you can also make a plane array into observable using `ko.utils.arrayMap` by looping and finally pushing into `self.g`(in your case)

Working fidde [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/74dh736s/9/)

**Side Note:** When something is not changing make up your mind that is not observable back track the issue

Comment: thanks, just one more thing - is it possible to ensure that "schemaconditiondetails" is the child of "eventschemacondition" in $data rather than "schema" as its now.., I think if this becomes possible,  then my subscribe and event calls will also start working..

Comment: well i just taken a sneak-peak at it i am not sure why it is like this `schema:{schema:""` i hope we are not doing anything like that . for all good reasons i suggest you to refer this question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091175/unable-to-map-the-data-using-mapping-plugin-knockout  to learn mapping with multiple loops by this you can make everything clean and readable . cheers and i'll look into that when i get time